# Finding the limit of a trig function with a zero in the denominator

Tags: calculus, limits

I was told to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^{10}\cos\left(\frac{{\pi}}{5x^4}\right)$$

I know the answer is $0$ since $x^{10} = 0^{10} = 0$, but obviously that is not enough to get full marks. I know that I need to get rid of the $x$ in the denominator of the cosine function, but I just don't know how to. How would I get rid of it?

Comment: Squeeze theorem?

Comment: ^ That's all I can think of. Do you know the squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct with your observation that $x^{10}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. To complete, observe that for any $x\neq 0$, we get
$$-1\leq \cos\frac{\pi}{5x^4}\leq 1$$ so that we get (since $x^{10}>0$ for $x\neq 0$)
$$-x^{10}\leq x^{10}\cos\frac{\pi}{5x^4}\leq x^{10}.$$
Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}(-x^{10})=0=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{10}$$ it follows from the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg(x^{10}\cos\frac{\pi}{5x^4}\bigg)=0.$$